# css height property won't apply to html img but width does

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a logo next to the "Animal adoption center" using height 100%. The height property can be seen on the img in the developer tools as 100% but isn't being applied. However, the width property does work. The parent property isn't height = 0 and has height so that shouldn't be the issue. I'm confused why the width would work and the height wouldn't. Also, the img source is an svg.

## TLDR

`height: 100%` won't work on the `site-logo` but `width:`  does.

Thanks for your help :)

## What's rendered

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO9VO.jpg)

The blue outline represents the "header-content" div which is the image's parent element.

## html

```html
<div id="header-bar">
    <div id="header-content">
        <!-- The site logo -->
        <img id="site-logo" src="assets/logo.svg" alt="site-logo">
        <div id="title-wrapper">
            <h1 id="website-title">{{websiteTitle}}</h1>
            <h4 id="selected-center-city-name">{{currentStoreCity}} Center</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## css

```css
#header-bar {
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#header-content {
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#site-logo {
   height: 100%;
}

#title-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
}

#website-title {
    margin-left: 25px;
}

#selected-center-city-name {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What is your end goal here? Do you want the logo to be the full height and the two pieces of text next to it? for the second header, do you want it all the way to the right? What's the alignment?

You probably want flexbox for this.

Comment: You need to define height value of #header-bar without percent. I faced that issue and i solved on this way. I’m gonna follow this question. If there is another way can someone help?

Comment: @davidleininger The end goal is like you said; to have the logo the full height of both headers. The alignment of the second header is right-aligned and is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. Idk if it's completely responsive, but a quick test was good. I added a non-relative height (`height: 75px;`) to the parent element and added `display: flex`. Thanks for the responses!

## working css

```css
#header-bar {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

#header-content {
    margin-left: 25px;
    height: 75px;
    display: flex;
}

#site-logo {
   height: 100%;
}

#title-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 25px;
    height: 100%;
}

#website-title {
    color: rgb(56, 56, 56);
}

#selected-center-city-name {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color:rgb(107, 107, 107);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the logo is an SVG, it will currently have an auto height that is tied to the graphic that will auto adjust to the width. there are a few ways you could go around doing this.

If the website needs to be responsive I would recommend making a seperate div and give it a class or ID of site logo. then rather than having it inserted as an IMG access the div in CSS and set the background image to the same URL for the svg. with that you can do a lot of size adjustments that will work more responsively if you need them to shrink or grow.

If you want to edit it the way that it is, you will need to increase the height more than what the base value is.
In html you can add:
height="200px" (or however big you want it)

in css you can do

height: 100px (change the px amount to whatever fits)
max-height: 100px (if you want their to be a max size for responsiveness)

you can use other measurements to change the size using things like rem, px, vw, vh. etc. I would look at this link to see all the different ways to change it based on what you need. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp

you could even adjust the scale if you want it to be an exact increment of its current Height and width ratio using transform: scale(1.5);